# To what degree does the site resemble your original vision for it?

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

@ETD, @Andrew, @Daniel and others:

Having visited your site a couple of times a month for years, I am not a heavy user; but, apparently, I like the site. I do not know which of you originally organized the site, but you and your friends have maintained it a long time. Thanks.

I am idly curious, though. To what degree does the site resemble your original vision for it?

If you can remember that far back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4 years ago... For me, it closely resembles my vision. The amount of traffic isn't high, but my hope for the site was simple. The Stack Exchange model is a benefit to any topic, and there isn't any other system of site that meets the standards of efficiency and usefulness that this system does.

Answer (score 2):

I think everyone should be reasonably happy that the site kinda survived, and serves a purpose for some members of the greater chess community, and for some specific topics. I thought the SE model would be both enabling and restrictive, and the results seem to be consistent. It is not a critical piece of the puzzle as far as chess sites go, but maybe this is for the best.